# How to make this an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

1. I am trying to make this code "move" from the left to right. I've been successful in moving it from to right. The problem is now, how do I run this infinitely? Okay I'm not familiar with C++ cause I'm a beginner. I tried to search the internet on how to make a code run infinitely, and I found a `for(;;)` loop, and I put it above where my first for loop will start. But it doesn't work. Can you give me tips or any hints?

   ```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
        string a;
        cout <<"Enter String : ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << '\n' << '\n' << '\n' << '\n';
        for(int x = 0; x <= 20; x++ ) {  
            Sleep(200);
            system("cls");
            cout <<"Enter String : ";
            cout << a;
            cout << '\n' << '\n' << '\n' << '\n';
            cout << setw(x)<< a;
        }
        for(int y = 20; y <= 20; y-- ) {
            Sleep(200);
            system("cls");
            cout <<"Enter String : ";
            cout << a;
            cout << '\n' << '\n' << '\n' << '\n';
            cout << setw(y)<<a;
        }
        return 0;
     }
   ```

The output should display like:

```
Enter string: Hello Friend


"Hello Friend" > it will move to the right and after 20 spaces.
                       <  now it move back to the left < "Hello Friend"
```

And also I saw a "Void" code what does it do? and is it relevant to my code?

Comment: What exactly are you asking about  please? Your _question_ is unclear! _"And also I saw a "Void" code what does it do? and is it relevant to my code?"_ One question per question here also please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main culprit is this line `for(int y = 20; y <= 20; y-- )` edit it to `for(int y = 20; y >= 0; y-- )` then put both for loop inside `while(1){ }`

here's the complete code:

```
int main ()
 {
     string a;
     cout <<"Enter String : ";
     cin >> a;
     cout << '\n' << '\n' << '\n' << '\n';

     while(1){ //infinite loop starts

     for(int x = 0; x <= 20; x++ ){  
     Sleep(200);
     system("cls");
     cout <<"Enter String : ";
     cout << a;
     cout << '\n' << '\n' << '\n' << '\n';
     cout << setw(x)<< a;
     }
     for(int y = 20; y >= 0; y-- ){ //make sure this condition
     Sleep(200);
     system("cls");
     cout <<"Enter String : ";
     cout << a;
     cout << '\n' << '\n' << '\n' << '\n';
     cout << setw(y)<<a;
     }

 }
     return 0;
}
```

"And also I saw a "`Void`" code what does it do? and is it relevant to my code?":  Basically it means "nothing" or "no type".
There are 3 basic ways that void is used:

Function argument: `int func(void)` -- the function takes nothing.same as `int func()`

Function return value: `void func(int)` -- the function returns nothing

Generic data pointer: `void* data` -- 'data' is a pointer to data of unknown type, and cannot be dereferenced.
and NO it is NOT relevant to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can write an infinite loop like this:

```
while (1){
  //do coding
}
```

While loops run while the statement inside () is true. 1 is always true.
You can use "break;" to stop an infinite loop whenever you wish to do so.

Comment: `while(1)` is more C-style. We should prefer explicit booleans like `while(true)` in C++

Comment: I don't really think it's worth while bothering over 1 or true :p

Comment: What about `while ("Elvis lives")`?

Comment: It should be `for (;;)`

Comment: @g.tsh that comment made my day :D